# Why is dill much faster and more disk-efficient than pickle for numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, serialization, pickle, dill

I'm using Python 2.7 and NumPy 1.11.2, as well as the latest versions of dill ( I just did  the `pip install dill`) , on Ubuntu 16.04.

When storing a NumPy array using pickle, I find that pickle is very slow, and stores arrays at almost three times the 'necessary' size.

For example, in the following code, pickle is approximately 50 times slower (1s versus 50s), and creates a file that is 2.2GB instead of 800MB.

```
 import numpy 
 import pickle
 import dill
 B=numpy.random.rand(10000,10000)
 with open('dill','wb') as fp:
    dill.dump(B,fp)
 with open('pickle','wb') as fp:
    pickle.dump(B,fp)
```

I thought dill was just a wrapper around pickle. If this is true, is there a way that I can improve the performance of pickle myself? Is it generally not advisable to use pickle for NumPy arrays?

EDIT: Using Python3, I get the same performance for `pickle` and `dill`

PS: I know about `numpy.save`, but I am working in a framework where I store lots of different objects, all residing in a dictionary, to a file.

Comment: Using python 3.6 and numpy 1.12.1 I get the same size for both files, can you try upgrading numpy

Comment: @EdChum Upgrading to 1.13.0 does not change anything. Using Python3 does

Comment: OK, I don't know the specific difference but it looks likely that this is some kind of optimisation that is only valid in python 3 which is weird

Comment: Do you know of any argument against using dill for numpy arrays? Otherwise I'd just go with that

Comment: Not really, I've never used `dill` but it seems to be an extension of pickle plus you can save a session state so it should just work fine.

Comment: Python 2 has a faster `cPIckle`.  That is the standard version in Python 3.

Comment: @hpaulj This doesn't do the trick. On my machine, using `cPickle` instead does not make any difference in runtime and memory consumption

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This ought to be a comment, but I have not enough reputation... My guess is that this is due to the pickle protocol used.

On Python 2, the default protocol is 0 and highest supported protocol is 2.
On Python 3, the default protocol is 3 and highest supported protocol is 4 (as of Python 3.6).

Each protocol version improves on the previous one, but protocol 0 is especially slow for largish objects. It should be avoided in most cases, except if you need to be able to read your pickles using extremely old versions of Python. Protocol 2 is already much better.

Now, I ***suppose*** dill uses pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL by default, and if that is indeed the case, it would probably be the cause of a good deal of the speed difference. You could try using pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL to see if you get similar performance using dill and standard pickle.

```
with open('dill', 'wb') as fp:
    dill.dump(B, fp, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
with open('pickle', 'wb') as fp:
    pickle.dump(B, fp, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

Answer (score 22):

I'm the `dill` author.  `dill` is an extension of `pickle`, but it does add some alternate pickling methods for `numpy` and other objects.  For example, `dill` leverages the `numpy` methods for the pickling of arrays.

Additionally, (I believe) `dill` uses `DEFAULT_PROTOCOL` by default (not `HIGHEST_PROTOCOL`), for python3, and for python2 it uses `HIGHEST_PROTOCOL` by default.